# Convert absolute file path to raster databaset

Tags: python, arcpy, geoprocessing, modelbuilder, arctoolbox

I wrote a simple python script that outputs an absolute path as string to a GeoTiff file. So this file can be treated as Raster.

In a Model, the GeoTiff file is to be the input raster of a CopyRaster arctool procedure. I dragged the python script in the Model and realised CopyRaster only accepts Raster Dataset as input but not the string.

How can I make the python script work the CopyRaster tool?

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "outputs an absolute path as string to a GeoTiff file"?

Comment: It outputs a file path as "string" type of data to the GeoTiff file.

Comment: How can you write a string to a tiff file? It still isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion it causes. What I meant was the script outputs a string which is an absolute path to a geotiff file, e.g. "c:\arcgis\results\goodfile.tif". Thanks

Comment: If you are using python, then why don't you call the Copy Raster tool from python itself? why do you need to make a model and run it within ArcGIS?

Comment: The python script I wrote is to always retrieve the latest GeoTiff file by modified date, hence it returns a string for the absolute path to the file. Then this tif file will be used as input to CopyRaster arc tool.